# I got a returned string from my StringRequest but I cant copy the string to another variable or even customize my listview

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have two classes :
**MainActivity class**  and it contains the following code to customize my listview but I always got an error and I do not know what the wrong.
What I am trying to do is to got a string from response variable and then convert it to JSONObject and fill the Arraylist to use it with my customadapter but the problem is that it coudnt copied to arraylist I do not know what the wrong .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<String> title_list = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> c_count_data = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv00);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, (new  MY_URL().MY_URL)+"api/api_count.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){
            response = response.replaceAll("\\s+","");
            JSONArray jArray;
            JSONObject jObject;

            try {
                jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                c_count_data.add(0, (String) jObject.get("NAM"));
                c_count_data.add(1, (String) jObject.get("SAM"));
                c_count_data.add(2, (String) jObject.get("EUO"));
                c_count_data.add(3, (String) jObject.get("ASI"));
                c_count_data.add(4, (String) jObject.get("AFR"));
                c_count_data.add(5, (String) jObject.get("AUS"));


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }



    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(ListView00Activity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    RequestQueue re = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    re.add(request);


            title_list.add(0, "North America");
            title_list.add(1, "South America");
            title_list.add(2, "Europe");
            title_list.add(3, "Asia");
            title_list.add(4, "Africa");
            title_list.add(5, "Australia");
            lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,this,title_list,c_count_data));

}
```

}

**My adapter class is :**

```
 Context context;
Activity activity;
ArrayList<String> n_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> c_arr = new ArrayList<String>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, ArrayList<String> n_arr, ArrayList<String> c_arr) {
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.n_arr = n_arr;
    this.c_arr = c_arr;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return n_arr.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return n_arr.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v =    inflater.inflate(R.layout.model, (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(R.id.parent_viewgroup),false);
    TextView count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tit);
    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc);
    count.setText(c_arr.get(i));
    name.setText(n_arr.get(i));




    return  v;








}}
```

**The error message is:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
                  at com.mypro.theproject_v1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:89)
```

**Thank you for your appreciated help in advance ...**

Comment: You can check my answer . @Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

Just judging from the exception, I'd say that `lv` is null when `lv.setAdapter(...)` is called, i.e. 
`final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv00);` does not find your view. Please check that first.

Your Request is most likely still in the queue when `lv.setAdapter(...)` is called and the NPE hits, so your whole Request and Adapter code isn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**change**

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv00);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**to**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv00);
```

**Note**
`findViewById` method need to call after `setContentView` method .